# Combination of convex and multiplicative structures

Tags: terminology

Combination of linear and multiplicative structures gives an algebra. What if instead of a linear structure one has a convex one? Is there a term for this?

A natural example is provided, for instance, by the space of all probability measures on a group (with the multiplicative operation provided by convolution).

Comment: "Convex algebra" sounds good to me, although it might provoke confusion with the term "locally convex algebra," which I believe means a topological algebra which is locally convex as a topological vector space. Another natural class of examples are the unit balls of Banach algebras.

Comment: I also thought about "convex algebra", but couldn't find a single use.